# GoToStateAction and KeyTrigger missing from System.Windows.Interactivity

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, caliburn.micro

I am using [MediaOwl](http://mediaowl.codeplex.com/) to help me get going with [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/).

In MediaOwl I removed the reference to `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions` and added a reference to `System.Windows.Interactivity`. Which seemed like the right thing to do.

The problem is that I cannot find a replacement for the classes mentioned in the title: `GoToStateAction` and `KeyTrigger`.

What would be the right fix for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KeyTrigger` is still in the Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll in the `Microsfort.Expression.Interactivity.Input` namespace.

`GoToStateAction` is also still in the Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll in the `Microsfort.Expression.Interactivity.Core` namespace.

Comment: Downloaded Blend SDK 3 and referenced Interactions. I can find `GoToStateAction` with the object browser but I still get `The tag 'GoToStateAction' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2008/interactions'`. What am I missing?

Comment: @ondesertverge: If you are using the SDK 3 then you'll need to use the "clr-namespace" style URN for your aliases. Since you tagged your question silverlight-4.0 I assumed you were using the latest version.

Comment: Foolish me ... Installing the SDK for SL4 was all that was needed. Thanks so much.